# CSS Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<header>
    Header
</header>

<nav>
    Nav
</nav>

<article>
    Article
</article>

<div>
    <aside>
        Aside
    </aside>

    <section>
        Section
    </section>
</div>

<footer>
    Footer
</footer>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
header {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: khaki;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

article {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;

}

div {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

aside {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 2em; 
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Very basic coding, just trying to understand how to make a responsive page.
Im trying to make it so when the device width is less than 800 px, all elements should stack above each other

And when the device is less than 500px all elements should stack above each other but the Aside and Section elements should disappear.

I figured I need to use viewport, and found a tutorial with code like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  ...continued
}
```

Not sure if that's the type of code I need to add to my CSS page or if I'm just over complicating it which I do often.

Comment: you are on the good way, try to play with this code in a snippet to see what it does. The rule in your example will only apply for screen devices (not on print), and if width >= 600px and it will resize colums to those particular dimensions. If you add another rule like this for the other "breakpoints", then your layout will change as the screen's width changes

Comment: Please make sure your example is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better answers more quickly. Walls of irrelevant code make more work for people that could help you and don't contribute anything. Additionally, make sure you're asking a specific question instead of asking for someone to write code for you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I think,You should try it

```
@media only screen (min-width:500px) and (max-width: 800px) {
 aside {                                                          
  display:none 
 }
 section {
  display:none
 }                                                                          
}
```

and this may be help you https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: That is basically what I did, but in the 800px part the footer disappears (pretty sure covered up from the other ones. No clue how to fix that

Comment: try this way  (min-width: 500 px) and (max-width: 800px)  this way you will get a property between 500px-800px